# DbProviderFactory Set ConnectionTimeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, oracle11g, dbproviderfactories

Is there a possibility to change the connection timeout when we are using `System.data.Common.DbProviderFactory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check your connectionString to see if everything is fine to access the Database.

A `DBProviderFactory` instance just return the abstrations of the `System.Data.Common`. The real type comes from your ado.net provider (`SqlClient`, `OracleClient`, etc.).

When you do something like:

```
IDbConnection connection = dbFactory.CreateConnection();
connection.Open();
```

The `connection` object is an abstration but the `dbFactory.CreateConnection()` will return a concrete type of `OracleConnection` or `SqlConnection` as your provider.

Comment: There is no problem with my connection string. Some of the actions I ask on the sql server can take up to 1min. When I try to modify the "connection.connectionTimeout", i get an error telling me that the connectionTimeout is readonly. So, I was wondering if there were any possibility to ask for a certain timeout when I create the connection. Also, createConnection doesn't take any parameters...

Answer (score 1):

For those who really are trying to change the connection timeout, not the command timeout, as I was when Google brought me to this page, you can do so by adding a Connection Timeout attribute to your connection string:

```
"DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/mydatabase;USER ID=MY_USERNAME;PASSWORD=mypassword;Connection Timeout=60"
```

Answer (score 0):

You were probably trying to set a command time out. Connection timeout is how long the computer will look for a server before giving up and deciding the db server is down.

Command time out is how long you want a query to run before you want it to give up waiting for the query to finish.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx